# Inconsistent equations when using the scalar product?

Tags: vectors

I'm given that two lines $m_1$ and $m_2$ pass through the origin and have directions $i+j$ and $i+k$ respectively. I am required to find the directions of the two lines $m_3$ and $m_4$ that pass through the origin and make angles of $\frac{\pi}{4}$ with both $m_1$ and $m_2$. To do this, I considered a line with direction vector
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a\\ 
b\\ 
c
\end{pmatrix}$$
and found the scalar product of this direction vector with the direction vectors of $m_1$ and $m_2$ to obtain the $2$ equations
$$\frac{\sqrt2}{2}=\frac{a+b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}\sqrt2}$$
and
$$\frac{\sqrt2}{2}=\frac{a+c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}\sqrt2}.$$
I then set $a=1$ and tried to solve these equations simultaneously, but doing this gave me an inconsistent equation. I used another method from an online solution and found that $a$ is not equal to $0$, so I don't understand what is wrong with the first method. Can someone explain what is wrong with it?

Comment: ahh this is my first time trying to use latex, looks like it came out wrong

Comment: I fixed that for you. Could you please check that everything is correct?

Comment: Thank you, yeah everything is correct. Why did it come out wrong when I typed it?

Comment: Math.SE supports single dollars signs `$ $` and double dollar signs `$$ $$` to write Latex. I never saw `[latex][/latex]` here so I don't think that is supported.

Comment: "gave me an inconsistent equation": can you explain ?

Comment: I was making a really stupid mistake :s it doesn't give me an inconsistent equation and I was being an idiot, sorry. However, by substituting a as 1, I only get one of the lines m3/m4. What's the best way to do this question to find both lines?

Answer (score 1):

For $a=1$, the two equations imply $b=c$. So you have
$$
1+b=\sqrt{1+2b^2}
$$
and
$$
1+2b+b^2=1+2b^2
$$
that gives $b(2-b)=0$. Both $b=0$ and $b=2$ are solutions for $1+b=\sqrt{1+2b^2}$.